# Iterating through array gives .map is not a function error in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to iterate through each element in the array and display it in the breadcrumb navigation.

What i am trying to do?
from a particular path or location say /list/item_id and if the item has certain information my breadcrumb navigation should change to the hierarchy of information.
For example, say i have the information of the item stored in item_information...and it is array of objects as below,

```
const item_information = [
{
    name: "c_name",

},
{
    name: "a_name",
},
{
    name: "name",
}
```

I want to retreive only the name of each object and store it in variable display and want to display that in the breadcrumb navigation....so to loop through each name value from the variable display i use .map function. In doing so , i get an error .map is not a function.

Below is the code,

```
class Crumb extends React.PureComponent {

render = () => {
    const link = this.props.link;
    let display;
    let match;
    let after_link;
    if (link === '/') {
        display = 'Home';

    } else if (match = link.match(/^\/list\/new$/)) {
        display = 'new item';

    } else if (match = link.match(/^\/list\/([^/]+)$/)) 
        if (this.props.item_information > 0) {
            display = this.props.item_information.map((el) => {
                return el.name;
            });
        } else {
            const model_id = match[1];
            const model = this.props.models && this.props.models.find(model 
                   => '' + model.id === model_id);
            display = itemname;
                after_link = 'after_link';
          }
    }

    //last part of the link
    if (!display) {
        const parts = link.split('/');
        display = parts[parts.length - 1];
    }
  return (
        <div>
            {Array.isArray(display) && display.map((display) => {
                return (
                    <div className="crumb">
                    <Link to={link}>{display}</Link>
                         </div>
                );
            })}
            <div className="crumb">
                <Link to={link}>{display}</Link>
            </div>
            {after_link}</div>

    );
};
```

}

```
class Breadcrumb extends React.PureComponent {
render = () => {
    const path = this.props.location.pathname;
    const crumbs = [];
    path.split('/').slice(1).forEach((part, index, parts) => {
        crumbs.push('/' + parts.slice(0, index + 1).join('/'));
    });
    return (
        <div className="breadcrumb">
            {crumbs.map((link, i) => {
                return (
                    <Fragment key={link}>
                        <Crumb
                            item_information={this.props.item_information}/>
                    </Fragment>);
            })}
        </div>
    );
};
```

}

Could someone help me in getting rid off the error .map is not a function. thanks.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz link for this?

Comment: On which line do you get the error ?

Comment: `this.props.item_information > 0` that should be `this.props.item_information.length > 0`

Comment: Is this the solution? Then add It as an answer maybe.

Comment: I can't tell if this was intentional on your part but your array definition is missing a closing bracket.